# Shell script to check if file exists in user home

Tags: macos, shell-script

I want to check if the User home on OS X has a file `environment.plist` in `.MacOSX` folder and if this file exists then append some new key values into it.

But if it does not exists then create this file with new key values. I am new to OS X so I don't know how to get user home and perform these checking, one of my friends told me I can do this by writing shell script.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Manually editing the file

Note that you can also always just go into the Terminal and write:

```
mkdir -p ~/.MacOSX
touch ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
open ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

and edit the file accordingly, if [that's what you are trying to do](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html). You should preferably use Apple's own Property List Editor.app, which comes with [Xcode 3](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792). Surely there are other editors with support for `plist` files, but I can't recall any right now.

If you want, you can also just `open ~/.MacOSX/` and then open the `plist` file with any other text editor, as long as you keep the right format.

---

#### With a shell script

But, in your question you asked for something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
FILE=~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
PLIST=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

# if the file doesn't exist, try to create folder
if [ ! -f $FILE ]
then
  mkdir -p ~/.MacOSX
fi

# then just add entries (file will be created if it doesn't exist)
$PLIST -c "Add :Variable1 string 'Value1'" $FILE
$PLIST -c "Add :Variable2 string 'Value2'" $FILE
```

This script will create the file if it doesn't exist already and then add two variables to it. Their names are `Variable1` and `Variable2`, respectively, and their values are `Value1` and `Value2`.

If the file already exists, the variables and values are just appended.

Copy this code, paste it to a file named, for example, `script.sh`. Save it to your home folder. Open the Terminal, then run

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Now you can run it with `./script.sh` and it will create the `environment.plist` file.

If you want to remove the `plist` file again, just enter

```
rm ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

The folder will remain, but that's not really a problem.

Comment: He wants to add values *if it exists*. I suggest `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` for that.

Comment: Thanks for plist editor suggestion but I want to do this from shell script. It would be helpful if you could also help me out in modifying the existing plist as I don't know the complexity of script.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, right. Updated :) @Sandy I edited my answer to use `PlistBuddy` as Daniel suggested. It basically just appends the variables and creates the file if necessary. What else do you need?

Comment: @Sandy slhck responded to your comment. (slhck: I think it's still only one @notification per comment)